# jQuery Validate Groups and Early Success

Tags: jquery, validation

I am trying to validate a 3 field SSN. I am validating these fields (and other fields on my form) on the fly, and showing a green check if the field validates and a red x if it doesn't, along with the error message.

The problem is that with the way I currently have it set up, the success function is firing after the first SSN field, showing the green checkmark before the other 2 fields have even been inputted. Of course, if they leave the second field at this point, they get the error, but how I can set it up so it only validates this group after the third one has been typed into. The code is below...

```
$('form').validate({

onfocusout: function(element) { $(element).valid(); } ,

rules: {
    tbSSN1:           {required: true, minlength: 3, regexp: /^[0-9]*$/},
    tbSSN2:           {required: true, minlength: 2, regexp: /^[0-9]*$/},
    tbSSN3:           {required: true, minlength: 4, regexp: /^[0-9]*$/},
    DOBMonth:         {required: true},
    DOBDay:           {required: true},
    DOBYear:          {required: true}
},

messages: {
    tbSSN1:           'Please enter your SSN to retreive your free credit scores.',
    tbSSN2:           'Please enter your SSN to retreive your free credit scores.',
    tbSSN3:           'Please enter your SSN to retreive your free credit scores.',
    DOBMonth:         'Please enter your DOB to retreive your free credit scores.',
    DOBDay:           'Please enter your DOB to retreive your free credit scores.',
    DOBYear:          'Please enter your DOB to retreive your free credit scores.'
},

groups: {
    SSN: "tbSSN1 tbSSN2 tbSSN3",
    DOB: "Month Day YearDropDown"
},

errorElement: "span",

highlight: function(element, errorClass) {
    var ep = $(element).parent();
    console.log(ep.find('label'));
    $(element).addClass('error');
    ep.find('label').css('color','red');
    ep.find('span.errorX').remove();
    ep.find('label').after('<span class="errorX"></span>');
},

success: function(label) {
    var lp = $(label).parent();
    label.addClass("valid"); 
    lp.find('input').removeClass('error'); 
    lp.find('label').css('color','black'); 
    lp.find('span.errorX').remove();
}
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Make use of the `required` method: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/required#dependency-expression

Answer (score 0):

A quick way to handle this would be attach to blur event on the last field and have it set a flag that would be checked when the validation logic is executed. If the flag isn't set then the logic terminates then and there and doesn't modify the DOM.